# "Inverse" of the inscribed angle theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

While doing geometry problem I encountered something I would call "inverse" of inscribed angle theorem. At first I wanted to state it like this:

> Given $\triangle$ABC and point O such that $\angle$BOC = 2$\angle$BAC it implies that O is the centre of the circle described on the $\triangle$ABC

But of course it is easy to show that this statement doesn't hold. But on my native language forum I found that this theorem should hold:

> Given $\triangle$ABC and $\angle$A = $\alpha$ and point O lying on the perpendicular bisector of the segment BC with $\angle$BOC = 2$\alpha$ and point O lying on the same side of line BC as point A then point O is the centre of the circle described on $\triangle$ABC

I realised that this theorem is sufficient for my problem, but after several attempts I am not able to prove this. Is it really right?

Comment: There are two points $O$ on the bisector of $BC$ such that $\angle BOC=2\alpha$.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't stated in that article at forum, but i think O needs to be at the same side of line BC as point A. I will change it now

Comment: It should be noted that it’s the perpendicular bisector

Comment: Okay, corrected, sorry for this mistake but i usually don't do geometry in English

Comment: Also, the word that I think you’re looking for is converse

Comment: Be sure to take proper care in the situation $\alpha > \pi/2$. That would change the situation a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is a point $O’\ne O$ satisfying the conditions. [image]

Then $CBO’=CBO=90-\alpha$ so $O’BO=0$ and then $O=O’$.

Comment: Note: If $\alpha>90$ then the proof is analogous (just use directed angles)